# Cut delimited with unescaped space?

Tags: cut, whitespace

I have a file with text in the format of:

```
User\ Name My\ Password
```

*Notice this is actually a 2 column file, where columns contain escaped spaces.*

`cut -d' ' -f2` produces `Name` but I want to produce `My Password`.

Is it possible to use `cut` and delimited only based on non-escaped spaces? If not, what alternate command can I use?

Comment: Short answer: no. Use sed.

Comment: I saw your other question, you could use a special character to separate your columns. Then there is no need to escape the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest GNU **`grep`** approach:

Sample `input.txt`:

```
User\ Name My\ Password
first\ field second\ field
```

---

Cut the 2nd field from *2-columned* file:

```
grep -Po '[^\\]\x20\K.*' input.txt
```

The output:

```
My\ Password
second\ field
```

---

Or the same with **`sed`**:

```
sed 's/.*[^\\]\x20\(.*\)/\1/' input.txt
```

**----------**

The crucial regex pattern part is `[^\\]\x20` that matches a space `\x20`(space hex code) if it's preceded by any char except escaping backslash `[^\\]`